# All the Whitespace Characters? Is it language independent?

Tags: language-agnostic, whitespace

I was wondering if all the language treats the same set of characters as white space charactes or is there any variation.

Can anyone provide complete list of White space characters separating the one which can be entered from keyboard? If it's different, the difference and the reason would be more appropriate. Any language is helpful if you don't bring out `Whitespace` or its variants(if any). I certainly don't want a complete list for language like `Whitespace` :)

Comment: Well, [this language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) certainly has different whitespace characters from other languages.

Comment: `U+1361` is "ETHIOPIC WORDSPACE", which sounds like a language-specific space character.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Whether a particular character is categorized as a whitespace character or not should depend on the *character set* being used.  That said, it is not impossible that a programming language can make its own definition of what constitutes whitespace.

Most modern languages use the Unicode Character set, which *does* have a definition for **space separator characters**.  Any character in the `Zs` category is a **space separator**.

[You can see the complete list here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm). In addition you can grep for `;Zs;` in the official [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) to see those characters. Note that the number of characters in this category may grow as new Unicode versions come into existence, so I will not say how many such characters exist, nor even *attempt* to list them.

In addition to the **Zs** Unicode *category*, Unicode also defines [character *properties*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property). Among the properties defined by Unicode is a Whitespace property. As of Unicode 7.0, characters with this property include all of the characters with category Zs plus a few *control characters* (including U+0009, U+000A, U+000B, U+000C, U+000D, and U+0085). You can find all of the characters with the whitespace property [at Unicode.org here](http://unicode.org/charts/uca/chart_Whitespace.html).

Now many languages, even modern ones, have special symbols for regular expressions such as `\s` or `[:space:]` but beware, these only refer to certain characters from the ASCII set; generally these are restricted to

- SPACE (codepoint 32, U+0020)
- TAB (codepoint 9, U+0009)
- LINE FEED (codepoint 10, U+000A)
- LINE TABULATION (codepoint 11, U+000B)
- FORM FEED (codepoint 12, U+000C)
- CARRIAGE RETURN (codepoint 13, U+000D)

Now this list is interesting because it contains not only space separators (Zs), but also from the "Control, Other" category (Cc).  This is what a programming language generally means when it uses the term "whitespace."

So probably the best way to answer your question for a "complete list" of whitespace characters is to say "it depends on what you mean."  If you mean "classic whitespace" it is probably the six characters listed above.  If you want something more "modern" then it is the union of those six with all the characters from the Unicode category Zs.  Then again, you might need to look within other blocks, too (e.g., U+1361 as mentioned in a comment to your question by Jerry Coffin).  It also depends on what you intend to *do* with these space characters.

Now one last thing: Unicode doesn't have every character in the world yet; it keeps growing.  It is possible that someday new space characters will be added.  For now, category Zs + the classics are your best bet.

Comment: Ray, your answer went into such great depth that I just want to post this comment so you'll probably get notified of this comment that you are missing 3 characters, which you can find in my separate answer. But because your answer went into such great depth, I just wanted to give you a friendly 'shout' so you can update your answer how you so choose. cheers! P.S. Thanks for your great info!

Comment: Thanks, @ShawnKovac, updated. The original answer only discussed the 17 characters with category Zs, so I expanded it to include the ones with the _whitespace character property_, which added eight (not just three). You are right that as of Unicode 7.0 there are 25 characters with that property.

Comment: But your answer gave another five that was not in that category Zs list, when i read your answer. Maybe that was after your 'original'. But i see you quite improved it. I love your great new resource links too, Ray! Thanks for those new ones!

Comment: No problem. It's true that the regex symbol `\s` has _always_ included the five characters U+0009 through U+000D that have Unicode category `Cc` ("Other-Control"). So what evolved was separate Unicode _categories_ for `Zs` and `Cc` as well as a Unicode _property_ to unify the space-like control characters with the symbolic-spaces. In my experience there tends to be better support for categories than properties (e.g. regexes with `\p{}`) but who knows--maybe that will change someday?

Comment: Thanks, @RayToal for your updated and even better explanation that the good one that you already had. Now i understand even better. Thanks for your very rich explanation. My paraphrase is that it's considerably more complicated that i had a clue it was! :)

Answer (score 16):

There are currently 25 Unicode whitespace characters with the following hexadecimal 'code points':

```
9, A, B, C, D, 20, 85, A0,
1680, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
2007, 2008, 2009, 200A, 2028, 2029, 202F, 205F,
3000
```

Corresponding decimal values are:

```
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 32, 133, 160,
5760, 8192, 8193, 8194, 8195, 8196, 8197, 8198,
8199, 8200, 8201, 8202, 8232, 8233, 8239, 8287,
12288
```

I originally acquired this information from Unicode.org, but my old link is no longer a working URL. Wikipedia has a nice page on the subject tho, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character if any are interested, which also gives 25 characters. (I have not cross-referenced that these characters are the same characters, but i trust that the Unicode Consortium has not made such a breaking, major change to their character set!)

I did find one simple page on unicode's website today, but it looks a bit more like a draft html page rather than anything supporting or claiming an official stance. But it does match what Unicode had previously posted as an official claim regarding what all of their whitespace characters are. (The link is in my comment below my answer.)

Comment: 133 or 0x85 is not a whitespace it is the <next-line> control character.

This opens another can of worms, control characters that don't control anything and are rendered as spaces.

Comment: @Lothar: I beg to differ. The official website indicates that it is. Here's but one example: https://unicode.org/charts/collation/chart_Whitespace.html

Comment: I have cross-referenced that the decimal values are the same characters as the wiki. Also check out the related Unicode characters `6158, 8203, 8204, 8205, 8288, 65279`.

Answer (score -6):

If you're looking for an efficient method, I use the following code:

```
(c <= 32 && c >= 0) || c == 127;
```

0 to 31 are the control characters, 32 is the SPACE character and 127 is the ESC character.  This works for all the character sets I know, including UTF-8.

Comment: FYI: this test does NOT work in any accurate capacity whatsover, even for ASCII and UTF-8. But what it does do is effectively test only the most *popular* ASCII characters. Also charater 127 is NOT the ESC character. Char 27 is Escape. Char 127 is the Del character and it is NOT a whitespace character. This *is* an accurate test instead for the 'non-printable' ASCII characters. These have similarities with whitespace characters, but they are still different. I wud equate them to being somewhat 'cousins' of one another in a loose analogy comparison. But one may ask for whitespace yet mean this.

Comment: It also tests for 32 which is a printable ASCII character. So no this is not an accurate test.

Comment: @Lothar, character 32 *IS* whitespace. That 'printable' ASCII character *is* whitespace, so it *should* check for character 32. It would be incorrect if it did not check for 32.