# Why does str.strip() automatically removes all the escape characters?

Tags: python, string

Sample a string:

```
a = '   \r\rwww someString www\r\r\n\n   '
```

and Sample the following two results.

```
[In]: a.strip()
[Out]: 'www someString www'

[In]: a.strip('w ')
[Out]: '\r\rwww someString www\r\r\n\n'
```

Python docs' comment on the str.strip([chars]) is:

> *If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace*

Why is it removing all the escape characters as well?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169006/all-the-whitespace-characters-is-it-language-independent

Comment: `\r` and `\n` (Carriage inwards and line feed) are white spaces as well.

Comment: `\n\r` are part of whitespacecs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

Comment: @Unihedron it's removing \t as well.

Comment: `\t` is also an escape sequence representing a white space. In fact the `/\s/` regex picks up a lot of white spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's doing exactly what it is supposed to do: strip *leading and trailing* characters.

Sample string:

```
a = '   \r\rwww someString www\r\r\n\n   '
```

This strips leading and trailing whitespace:

```
[In]: a.strip()
[Out]: 'www someString www'
```

`\r` and `\n` are whitespace characters, so they get stripped.

---

This strips leading and trailing `w` or literal space (character 32); it does not strip the `\r` or `\n` characters, which are whitespace characters:

```
[In]: a.strip('w ')
[Out]: '\r\rwww someString www\r\r\n\n'
```

Because it doesn't strip `\r` or `\n`, the `www` is left alone.

---

In both cases, the *internal* spaces are untouched.

Comment: To strip leading and trailing whitespace, you don't need any arguments; `a.strip()` will do it. But `.strip()` doesn't remove any internal spaces. To strip leading, trailing, and internal whitespace, `a = re.sub(r"\s", "", a)` will do it.