# Why does split() return more elements than split(" ") on same string?

Tags: python, string, split

I am using `split()` and `split(" ")` on the same [string](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/teach/Algorithms//7_hash_RBtree_simpleDS/hw_hash_RBtree/alice_in_wonderland.txt). But why is `split(" ")` returning less number of elements than `split()`? I want to know in what specific input case this would happen.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: split() will split with all special characters in a string. In split(' ') you are specifying the character by which you want to split the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with the `None` argument (or, no argument) splits on *all* whitespace characters, and this isn't limited to *just* the space you type in using your spacebar.

```
In [457]: text = 'this\nshould\rhelp\tyou\funderstand'

In [458]: text.split()
Out[458]: ['this', 'should', 'help', 'you', 'understand']

In [459]: text.split(' ')
Out[459]: ['this\nshould\rhelp\tyou\x0cunderstand']
```

List of all whitespace characters that `split(None)` splits on can be found at [All the Whitespace Characters? Is it language independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169006/all-the-whitespace-characters-is-it-language-independent)

Answer (score 3):

If you run the help command on the split() function you'll see this:

> split(...) S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the delimiter
>   string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done. If sep
>   is not specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator and
>   empty strings are removed from the result.

Therefore the difference between the to is that `split()` without specifing the delimiter will delete the empty strings while the one with the delimiter won't.

Answer (score 3):

The method `str.split` called without arguments has a somewhat different behaviour.

First it splits by any whitespace character.

```
'foo bar\nbaz\tmeh'.split() # ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'meh']
```

But it also remove the empty strings from the output list.

```
' foo bar '.split(' ') # ['', 'foo', 'bar', '']

' foo bar '.split() # ['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the split function splits on a specific string if specified, otherwise on spaces (and then you can access the result list by index as usual):

```
s = "Hello world! How are you?"
s.split() 
Out[9]:['Hello', 'world!', 'How', 'are', 'you?']
s.split("!")
Out[10]: ['Hello world', ' How are you?'] 
s.split("!")[0] 
Out[11]: 'Hello world'
```

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, the most confusion had come from `split()`'s different treatments on whitespace.

Having a separator like `' '` vs `None`, triggers different behavior of `split()`. According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Below is an example, in which the sample string has a trailing space `' '`, which is the same whitespace as the one passed in the second `split()`. Hence, this method behaves differently, not because of some whitespace character mismatch, but it's more of how this method was designed to work, maybe for convenience in common scenarios, but it can also be confusing for people who expect the `split()` to just `split`.

```
sample = "a b "
sample.split()
>>> ['a', 'b']
sample.split(' ')
>>> ['a', 'b', '']
```